# How to extract exception message from AWS DynamoDB python exception?

Tags: python, exception, message, amazon-dynamodb

I have the following block of Python code talking to DynamoDB on AWS:

```
try:
    response = conn.batch_write_item(batch_list)
except Exception ,e:
    try:
        mess = e.message
    except:
        mess = "NOMESS"

    try:
        earg0 = e.args[0]
    except:
        earg0 = "NOEARG0"

    try:
        stre = str(e)
    except:
        stre = "NOSTRE"

    print "mess = '%s'" % mess
    print "earg0 = '%s'" % earg0
    print "stre = '%s'" % stre
```

What I get is this:

```
mess = ''
earg0 = 'NOEARG0'
stre = 'DynamoDBValidationError: 400 Bad Request {'message': 'Item size has exceeded the maximum allowed size', '__type': 'com.amazon.coral.validate#ValidationException'}'
```

What I need to somehow reliably extract the `message` string such as `'Item size has exceeded the maximum allowed size'` from `e`. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using `boto` to access DynamoDB.

Here is the `JSONResponseError` (supersuperclass of `DynamoDBValidationError`) `__init__` method:

```
self.status = status
self.reason = reason
self.body = body
if self.body:
    self.error_message = self.body.get('message', None)
    self.error_code = self.body.get('__type', None)
    if self.error_code:
        self.error_code = self.error_code.split('#')[-1]
```

Wild guess: I would go with `e.error_message` to get 'Item size has exceeded ...'.

You can also print all attributes (and their values) of `e`:

```
for attr in dir(e): 
    print "e[%r] = '''%s'''" % (attr, getattr(e, attr))
```

Answer (score 0):

Take e.body, You will get the error as a dictionary.

example:
{u'message': u'The conditional request failed', u'__type': u'com.amazonaws.dynamodb.v20120810#ConditionalCheckFailedException'}

From this easily you will get message.